# Hibernate Session in background thread is always closed causing LazyInitializationException

Tags: hibernate, groovy, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to do some JPA reading-computing-then-saving work in a background thread started by a service method. I do all my work in a single @Transactional method of the service. A different method in that service starts the thread that processes it. However, if I try to access a lazy @oneToMany relationship, even if I do it immediately after retrieving the results the first time, I get LazyInitializationException - no session. How could there be no session? I JUST RETRIEVED A RESULTSET ONE LINE BEFORE.

Please ignore that thread pooling is not used here. This code is written in groovy so might be hard for java-only developers to understand.

```
@Service
public class NotifierService {
public void startNewNotifierThread() {
    stopNotifierThreadIfRunning()
    log.info "Starting notifier thread"

    notifierThread = new Thread({
        while(!Thread.interrupted()) {
            runNotifier()
            Thread.sleep(10000)
        }

        if(Thread.interrupted()) {
            log.info("Reached end of thread due to interrupt")
        }
    })

    notifierThread.start()
}

@Transactional public void runNotifier() {
    boolean isAlive0 = TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive()
    Session session = (Session) entityManager.getDelegate();
    Collection<User> allSubscribedUsers = userRepository.getAllSubscribedUsers()

    log.debug "Processing subscriptions for ${allSubscribedUsers.size()} subscribed users"

    int fcmMsgsSent = 0, apnMsgsSent = 0
    boolean isAlive1 = TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive()

    allSubscribedUsers.each { User user ->
        boolean isAlive2 = TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive()
        log.debug "Subscriptions for user ${user.email}: ${user.analysisSubscriptions.size()}"

        Set<AnalysisSubscription> updatedSubscriptions = new HashSet<AnalysisSubscription>()

        user.analysisSubscriptions.each { AnalysisSubscription subscription ->
            boolean isAlive3 = TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive()

            int numResults = subscription.analysisResults.size() //LAZYINITIALIZATIONEXCEPTION
        }
    }
}
```

The result of this code is isAlive0,isAlive1,isAlive2,isAlive3 are all false. The value of session.closed is true even at the start of the method which doesnt make sense why it is able to retrieve all subscribed users (it i using a repository underneath - which makes me suspect that method is using its own session...?). It seems like @Transactional is not working: it should OPEN a hibernate session and KEEP IT OPEN until the end of the method. It seems it is not even opening the session at all.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good article on how transaction management works in Spring with multiple threads. That seems very similar to your example.

The point is you can't start a new Thread() because the `Transaction` is related to thread local values, that are present only in current thread.

Probably you should load lazy references before leave valid thread or define `@Async`
 `@Transactional` Services

https://dzone.com/articles/spring-transaction-management-over-multiple-thread-1